# What exactly is meant by "partial function" in functional programming?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, partial-application, partial-functions

According to my understanding, partial functions are functions that we get by passing fewer parameters to a function than expected. For example, if this were directly valid in Python:

```
>>> def add(x,y):
...    return x+y
... 
>>> new_function = add(1)
>>> new_function(2)
3
```

In the snippet above, `new_function` is a partial function. However, according to the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions), the definition of partial function is

> A partial function is a function that is not defined for all possible arguments of the specified type.

so, my question is: what exactly is meant by "partial function"?

Comment: You are confusing a *partially applied* function with a *partial* function.

Comment: Python's `partial` performs [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), whereas Haskell does that automatically. The wiki entry refers to [*partial functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function), which is a term from mathematics.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Haskell doesn't do partial function application. Every function takes one argument, and function application applies a function to a single argument. Currying *simulates* what you would think of as partial application in another language by simulating multiple-argument functions in the first place. Something like `add 3 5` isn't a single function application. This first applies `add` to 3 to get a new function, which is then applied to 5.

Comment: And in C#, a `partial` method is a forward declaration of an _optionally_ implemented private method elsewhere in the project codebase.

Comment: Your example could be made valid: `new_function = functools.partial(add, 1)`

Comment: Your example (and thus the question) is invalid: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You are here confusing two concepts. A [*partially **applied** function* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application) with a [*partial function* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions).

A partially *applied* function is:

> Partial application in Haskell involves **passing less than the full number of arguments** to a function that takes multiple arguments.

whereas a partial function indeed is a non-total function:

> A partial function is a function that is not defined for all possible arguments of the specified type.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it could be improved by adding an example of a partial function to the answer itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that exact definition of a partially applied function. Functions in Haskell always only take one argument, never "multiple arguments". I would use the definition "partial application (partially applying functions) in Haskell involves supplying fewer than the full number of arguments needed to obtain a value that cannot be further applied to another argument." (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700022/1971805))

Comment: @TerryA This is a bit philosophical, but I would say that Haskell *has* mutli-argument functions and it *implements* that concept by mapping them to a particular pattern of simpler unary functions. `add x y = x + y` is a binary function and it is also a unary function that returns a function; in Haskell those are two equivalent ways of describing the same thing (one is not more correct than the other). "Partial application" is inherently a concept that arises when looking at things from the multi-argument viewpoint; there's no need for a clunky definition in terms of unary functions.

Answer (score 25):

A partial function (both in the context of functional programming and mathematics) is exactly what the wiki says: a function not defined for all of its possible arguments. In the context of programming, we usually interpret "not defined" as one of several things, including undefined behaviour, exceptions or non-termination.

An example of a partial function would be integer division, which is not defined if the divisor is 0 (in Haskell it will throw an error).

> in above snippet new_function is partial function.

That code would simply cause an error in Python, but if it worked as you intended, it would be a total (meaning not partial) function.

As commentors already pointed out, you're most likely thinking of the fact that it'd be a *partially applied* function.

Answer (score 21):

The answers explain all, I will just add one example in each language:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

f = add(1)
print(f(3))

    f = add(1)
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

this is **neither a partial function nor a curried function**, this is only a function that you **didn't gave all its arguments**.

A curried function in python should be like this:

```
partialAdd= lambda x: lambda y: x + y

plusOne = partialAdd(1)
print(plusOne(3))

4
```

and in haskell:

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus x y = x + y

plusOne = plus 1

plusOne 4

5
```

A partial function in python:

```
def first(ls):
    return ls[0]

print(first([2,4,5]))
print(first([]))
```

> output

```
2

print(first([]))
  File "main.py", line 2, in first
    return ls[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And in Haskell, as your [link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions) showed up:

```
head [1,2,3]
3

head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

> So what is a total function?

Well, basically the opposite: this is a function that will work for any input of that type. Here is an example in python:

```
def addElem(xs, x):
  xs.append(x)
  return xs
```

and this works even for infinite lists, if you use a little trick:

```
def infiniList():
    count = 0
    ls = []
    while True:
        yield ls
        count += 1
        ls.append(count)

ls = infiniList()
for i in range(5):
  rs = next(ls)

print(rs, addElem(rs,5))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And the equivalent in Haskell:

```
addElem :: a -> [a] -> [a]
addElem x xs = x : xs

addElem 3 (take 10 [1..])
=> [3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Here the functions don't hang forever. The concept is the same: for every list the function will work.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that python has support for [partial functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.partial) in the standard library.